# How do I create a basic Lucene index in exist-db?

Tags: xml, lucene, exist-db

I am trying to create a basic Lucene index in eXist-db. I do not see the index in the list of indexes using Monex and the index doesn't work when I query it. But when I reindex it returns "true()" when I run it manually or if I save the collection.xconf it says "Configurations applied".

My XML looks like this:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <text>
      <body>
         <superEntry xml:id="f1755-z-1-se">
            <entry xml:id="f1755-z-1" corresp="#f1773-z-1">
               <pb facs="f1755-z-1.jpg"/>
               <form type="variant">Z,</form>
               <sense xml:id="f1755-z-1.1" n="1">
                  <def>Is found in the <lang ana="#ang">Saxon</lang> alphabets, set down by Grammarians, but is read in no word originally <lang ana="#gem">Teutonick</lang>:</def>
                  <note type="pron">its sound is uniformly that of an hard S.</note>
               </sense>
            </entry>
         </superEntry>
      </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```

My index is like this:

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
  <index xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <lucene>
        <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
        <text qname="tei:def"/>
        <inline qname="tei:hi"/>
    </lucene>
</index>
```

The lucene query here returns nothing, but the other contains query returns results:

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
let $query := 
   <query>
     <term>found</term>
   </query>

return 
    collection('/db/apps/sjd/data')//tei:def[ft:query(.,$query)],
    collection('/db/apps/sjd/data')//tei:def[contains(.,"found")]
```

Is there an error in the index definition or query? What am I missing? Is there a way to see if indexes exist, other than the Monex indexes page? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You use eXist-db KWIC module (`ft:query`), so you have to "import" it in your code.
2. You have to use `for` to query your collection and only then `return` to show result one by one (see explanations about XQuery `FLWOR`).
3. Your index seems to be ok, but pay attention where you put your index. See [documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/indexing#idxconf):

> "[...] indexes are configured in collection-specific configuration
> files. These files are stored as standard XML documents in the system
> collection /db/system/config [...] To configure a given collection,
> for instance /db/foo, create a file collection.xconf and store it as
> /db/system/config/db/foo/collection.xconf. "

4. In your query, put `<term>` inside `<bool>` .

So try to check if you index is in the right place and then try this code:

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
import module namespace kwic="http://exist-db.org/xquery/kwic";
let $query := 
   <query>
        <bool>
             <term>found</term>
        </bool>
   </query>

for $hit in collection('/db/apps/sjd/data')//tei:def[ft:query(.,$query)]

return 
     kwic:summarize($hit, <config width="40"/>)
```

Finally, do not hesitate to look at the documentation for more details: [eXist-db KWIC](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/kwic)  and [eXist-db Fulltext index and search](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/lucene#query)

**UPDATE**: Your index miss the final close tag `</collection>`

Comment: Thank you!  I finally got it to work. The query works with or without the <bool>. I'll read up on that. I'll explain the actual problem in an update. And, now that I have the index I tried your query with kwic and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Great! If my answer solve your problem, please validate it as correct. If new problems arise, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it is reproducible. If you create an XML formatting syntax error in an index configuration and then reindex, the index disappears from the Monex list of indexes and there is nothing you can do to the file make the index compile. I kept trying to modify the index configuration and it did not look like there was any error, but the index never showed in the Monex list of indexes.

To fix it,

1. delete the collection.xconf file
2. reindex the collection
3. recreate the collection.xconf file (without the error, and in the right location (see ag_1812's comments above)
4. reindex

Comment: It’s not about the Monex. The problem was in a lot of mistakes in your XQuery and, probably, the missing closer tag in Index (see update) and, probably, the wrong location of your index. No need to re-index manually. _"The eXist-db index system automatically maintains and updates indexes"_  (see documentation: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/indexing#maintaining )